# Select an option of a html page

Tags: c#

Im trying to get my application to select an option out of a page

If looked on site for some help but could not find anything so some help would be nice

My code:

```
private void sellCars()
{
    HtmlElementCollection elements = this.get_mainframe_tags("img");
    IEnumerator enumerator2;
    elements = this.get_mainframe_tags("option");
    try
    {
        enumerator2 = elements.GetEnumerator();
        while (enumerator2.MoveNext())
        {
            HtmlElement element2 = (HtmlElement)enumerator2.Current;
            Console.WriteLine("Test = " + element2.GetAttribute("value").ToString() + "");
            if (element2.GetAttribute("value").ToString() == "sell")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Called");
                element2.SetAttribute("value", "sell");
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        enumerator2 = elements.GetEnumerator();
        if (enumerator2 is IDisposable)
        {
            (enumerator2 as IDisposable).Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `IEnumerator` by hand like that is pointless (and also wrong).  Use `foreach` or LINQ.

Comment: What exactly are you doing mate? Using webcontrols on a console app? By the way, in asp.net you can use server controls which expose an id property and makes things easier when trying to reference them rather than iterating (incorrectly) through the whole page control hierarchy. You really need to read a tutorial (or two)

Comment: I have fixed it now but i need a way to calc how many cars are on the page

This is what i use to select it 3 being a car 3-32 are cars

elements[3].SetAttribute("selectedIndex", num.ToString());